# H.264 I-Frame replacement

Tags: video, h.264, encoder, decoder

Is there any utility/tool that can replace single I-Frame in H.264 video chunk with another png/jpeg image, without touching B,P frames that are dependent on this I-Frame.

Answer (score 0):

As I think you have already worked out, because the other frames are dependent on the I-frame, changing it in the video encoding will mean they have to change, or else they will be incorrect.

However, depending on what you are trying to achieve you may be still able to create the same affect.

For example, if you control the player a simple overlay may be enough for you.

Alternatively, depending on how long you want the image to be visible, using a subtitle track with an image overlay which is timed to the scene you want to replace may work.

There are different formats for subtitles and different streaming protocols and servers may have different restrictions, but if this approach would work then it sounds like W3C TTML would be a good match.

The full spec is available here (at the time of writing): https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/CR-ttml2-20180313/ and you can see some discussion and examples here: https://github.com/rbouqueau/TTML_in_MP4_DASH_statement

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for reply. Yes I know that other frames are dependent on this IDR frame and I know that modification of IDR frame will have implication on further B,P frames. Anyway I want to replace it preserving the resolution of course. As B,P frames refere to uncompressed domain of IDR frame there will no be actual corruption but some kind of ghost effect.